# Redis not working when using browser

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have installed Apache and Redis on Centos 6.5 and Predis as PHP library. The problem is when I use `php /../filename.php` Redis works fine, but when run this page with browser, nothing happens.

Comment: Is the redis extension enabled in your php.ini for your web server?

Comment: php from the command line and php through your web server will usually have different php.ini files.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe on CentOS they use the same php.ini. Did you try restarting Apache?

Comment: thanks for reply, I checked php.ini file and make these changes:extension=redis.so, session.save_handler = redis, 
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost?weight=1", and restart apache server, but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

After restarting Apache, get "permission denied" error and solved with [this tutorial](http://williamjxj.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/redis-server-predis-permission-denied-setsebool/).

Specifically, run this from the command line to allow Apache to make socket connections:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1 
sudo  setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
```

Comment: OP, I've added your answer as an answer - this is generally considered better than marking questions as [solved] in the title. If you wish to click the tick mark, that 'accepts' the answer and takes it out of unanswered question lists. Even better, if you can create your own answer, that will reduce the need for this link-only answer, which could break in the future. Thanks.